# mediaPlayer.release() crashes my app java

Tags: java, android, performance

I have a project where I added a MediaPlayer in a custom Array Adapter and I make it take the Resource ID of the audio file from the Array List the problem is that I want to release the media player after the audio completes but every time I try to add release in OnCompletion and try to press a view while the media player plays a sound the app crashes .. I searched online and found a code but it gives me an error and I can't find the actual reason for such a crash.
that's the code for the on Click Listener and the Media player:

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), currentWord.getVoiceResourceID());

        // Wait for user's input by his click on the list's item to play the sound.
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Storing the return value of getVoiceResourceID() into mVoice.
                // I think this line can be ignored so we call the method inside the creation of the Media Player.
                // Creating our media player and put our track on it.
                mediaPlayer.selectTrack(currentWord.getVoiceResourceID());
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                                mediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

I hope I could fix that problem.

Comment: May you provide exception stack trace (from console/logcat)?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ed7ab364447d95d2464cbb86353a03e2